# Substrate-Connect Error on new ScProvider

Tags: javascript, substrate-connect

I am using Substrate Connect in the browser following the [docs](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/integrate-with-tools/integrate-a-light-client-node/) for a custom chain spec. When I try to create a new ScProvider like the documentation suggests i get an error that I am missing a variable in the constructor.

```
TS2554: Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 1.
    41 | // Create the provider for the custom chain
    42 |     const customSpec = JSON.stringify(jsonCustomSpec);
  > 43 |     const provider = new ScProvider(customSpec);
```

In the substrate lib the constructor code is asking for SubstrateConnect.
Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need at least the SubstrateConnect instance (And the relay chain in case of a parachain).

See the example to connect to [Statemint](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/master/parachains/chain-specs/statemint.json):

```
import { ScProvider} from "@polkadot/rpc-provider";
import * as Sc from "@substrate/connect";
import { ApiPromise } from "@polkadot/api";
import jsonParachainSpec from "./statemint.json";

 const relayProvider = new ScProvider(Sc, Sc.WellKnownChain.polkadot);
 const parachainSpec = JSON.stringify(jsonParachainSpec);
 const provider = new ScProvider(Sc, parachainSpec, relayProvider);
      
 await provider.connect();
```

Comment: this did it. thank you.
import * as Sc from "@substrate/connect";
then use the Sc in new ScProvider(Sc, spec);